# How to change the value of an Array object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrayobject

I have an array object call listOfObjects.

```
[{"name":"A", "data":"[{"value1":"1","value2":"2"}]"},
 {"name":"B", "data":"[{"value1":"1","value2":"2"}]"}]
```

What I want to do is insert an object into the array where the array is empty.If the array is not empty then do a check on the item inside. If item already exist, do update on the item, else add it to the array. Below is my code

```
  var searchName= "A"; 
  if (listOfObjects.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < listOfObjects.length; i++) {
                if (listOfObjects[i].name == searchName) {
                    listOfObjects[i].data = data;
                    break;
                } else {
                    insert = {
                        'name': searchName,
                        'data': data
                    };
                    listOfObjects.push(insert);
                }
            }
    } else {
        insert = {
            'name': searchName,
            'data': data
        };
        listOfObjects.push(insert);
   }
```

When I run it, even though A already exist, it update the existing item but also add one more time to the listOfObjects. Is there anyway that can achieve what I want? Thanks..

Comment: You have wrapped your inside array in `""` which means it is a string not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're inserting into the array **inside** your `for` loop looking for a match. Instead, remember whether you've seen a match and insert after the loop if you haven't. There's also no reason for the `length` check and no reason to repeat your logic for inserting:

```
var searchName= "A"; 
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; !found && i < listOfObjects.length; i++) {
    if (listOfObjects[i].name == searchName) {
        listOfObjects[i].data = data;
        found = true;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    listOfObjects.push({
        'name': searchName,
        'data': data
    });
}
```

---

Note that you can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (which can be polyfilled for old browsers) to find the entry rather than a `for` loop if you like:

```
var searchName= "A"; 
var entry = listOfObjects.find(function(entry) {
    return entry.name == searchName;
});
if (entry) {
    entry.data = data;
} else {
    listOfObjects.push({
        'name': searchName,
        'data': data
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all change this

```
[{"name":"A", "data":"[{"value1":"1","value2":"2"}]"},
 {"name":"B", "data":"[{"value1":"1","value2":"2"}]"}]
```

by

```
[{"name":"A", "data":[{"value1":1,"value2":2}]},
 {"name":"B", "data":[{"value1":"1","value2":"2"}]}];
```

because your list will `throw Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Answer (score 0):

Write another simple function to get the item listOfObjects[i] with selected searchName. Here 'getSearchObject()' function checks the existance of searchName and then add or updates array.

```
addOrRemoveItem() {
    let listOfObjects = [
      { "name": "A", "data": "[{'value1':'1','value2':'2'}]" },
      { "name": "B", "data": "[{'value1':'1','value2':'2'}]" }
    ],
      data = '[{"value1":"1","value2":"2"}]';
    var searchName = "C";
    if (listOfObjects.length > 0) {
      let searchObj = this.getSearchObject(listOfObjects, searchName);
      if (searchObj) {
        searchObj.data = data;
      } else {
        let insert = {
          "name": searchName,
          "data": data
        }
        listOfObjects.push(insert);
      }
    } else {
      let insert = {
        "name": searchName,
        "data": data
      }
      listOfObjects.push(insert);
    }
  }

  getSearchObject(objArr, searchKey) {
    var obj = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
      if (objArr[i].name === searchKey) {
        obj = objArr[i];
      }
    }
    return obj;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution that recognizes older JS engines (`filter` instead of `find`) but does always assume getting passed a list of unique items could be implemented like this ...

```js
function updateList(itemList, item) { // - always assume a list of unique items.
  var
    itemName = item.name,
    listItem = itemList.filter(function (elm) { // - assume `filter`, not find`.
      return (elm.name === itemName); // - find/get existing list  item by name.
    })[0];

  if (listItem) {
    listItem.data = item.data;
  } else {
    itemList.push(item)
  }
}


var list = [
  { "name": "A", "data": [ { "value1": "A1", "value2": "A2" }] },
  { "name": "B", "data": [ { "value1": "B1", "value2": "B2" }] },
  { "name": "C", "data": [ { "value1": "C1", "value2": "C2" }] }
];

console.log('list : ', list);


updateList(list,  { "name": "D", "data": [ { "value1": "D1", "value2": "D2" }] });

updateList(list,  { "name": "B", "data": [ { "value1": "b_1", "value2": "b_2", "value3": "b_3" }] });
updateList(list,  { "name": "C", "data": [ { "value3": "C3" }] });

console.log('list : ', list);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```